# Capturing Chrome extension console logs in Selenium

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I have a Chrome extension that calls console.log() in several places for debugging purposes. This output is visible in the Chrome web console. When I run selenium with ChromeDriver and load up the extension, I still see the output in the web console, but I cannot figure out a way to see the extension logs from the selenium script.

Trying `driver.get_log('<target>')` with any target specified [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Logging) returns logs from various parts of the selenium-driver-browser stack, but shows nothing from the extension. I'm also setting all log sources to `'ALL'` in `loggingPrefs`, as specified [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities#JSON_object).

I've also tried using [this](https://github.com/jasonm/ChromeJSConsoleCollector) extension to collect console output into the DOM and then try to read the DOM from the selenium script, but it appears that this extension does not (or cannot?) collect logs from other running extensions.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I wrote a small package to capture console logs in a descriptive way. You can inject its init code into the webpage where you want to capture the logs
https://www.npmjs.com/package/capture-console-logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this by modifying the extension I was testing to log straight to the DOM. This way, I can read the extension's output by reading HTML from the page in selenium. It's not pretty but it works.